# Quartz.Net Trigger Scheduled Job On Demand

Tags: quartz.net

I have some Quartz.Net jobs which are running on a Schedule

```
scheduler.ScheduleJob(
new JobDetailImpl("MarkAsSolutionReminderJob", typeof(MarkAsSolutionReminderJob)),
new CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl("MarkAsSolutionReminderJobTrigger", IntervalUnit.Hour, 6));
```

Is it possible for me to manually trigger this Job to run when I want it to?

So it continues to run as normal, but in a specific piece of code I might want to just run it out of schedule once or twice. But it doesn't affect the scheduled job?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to manually trigger this Job to run when I want it to?

Yes, you can trigger this job as and when you need.

Use `void TriggerJob(JobKey jobKey)` method for this as below:

```
scheduler.TriggerJob(new Jobkey("MarkAsSolutionReminderJob"));
```

If you want to pass some data to the job while executing it on demand, you can also do that by just using another overload `void TriggerJob(JobKey jobKey, JobDataMap data);` of the same method as below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//populate dictionary as per your needs
JobDataMap jobData = new JobDataMap(data);
scheduler.TriggerJob(new Jobkey("MarkAsSolutionReminderJob"),jobData);
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see updated question, I have tried this code but it does not work.

Comment: @leen3o have you persisted the job previously in the database?

Comment: this worked great. There was an error in the task before my debug point! Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to run the job without actually schedulling it?

Comment: @UlyssesAlvesWhy not call a function directly if you dont want to schedule it? Quartz is used to run the function/job on particular schedules.

Comment: Should scheduler be started for this? If yes, then will it not also schedule the same job? I specifically don't want to schedule it but run only once.